# Recursive function does not return any value

Tags: php, recursion, factorial

I want to understand why this function doesn't return anything.

```
function fact($n, $p = 1) {
    if ($n > 1) {
        $p *= $n--;
        fact($n, $p);
    } else {
        return $p;
    }
}

var_dump(fact(5)); // NULL
```

Comment: try `return fact($n, $p);`

Comment: Because you're only returning on the base case, the results of the non-base case are never communicated back. As the above guy said, you need to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is a looping construct which comes from functional languages. So yes, as others noted, your function doesn't work correctly because the *true* branch of your `if` statement doesn't return anything. However, I have additional remarks about your code

```
function fact($n, $p = 1) {
    if ($n > 1) {
        // this makes it hard to reason about your code
        $p *= $n--;
        return fact($n, $p);
    } else {
        return $p;
    }
}
```

You're actually mutating *two* variables here in *one* expression. It's clever if you're trying to keep the code looking shorter, but there's actually an even better way.

```
function fact($n, $p = 1) {
    if ($n > 1) {
        $p *= $n--;
        // just compute the next values; no need to update $p or $n
        return fact($n - 1, $p * $n);
    } else {
        return $p;
    }
}
```

Now we don't have to think about how `$p` and `$n` change individually. We just know that we call `fact` again with the *next* values for each state of `$p` and `$n`.

Keep in mind, these principles are so strong in some functional programming languages that reassignment of variables likes `$p` and `$n` is not even allowed.

---

Lastly, we have to talk about your your API leak, `$p`. If someone were to specify a value when calling `fact`, they could get the wrong answer or trigger an error

```
// bad !
fact(5, 10); // => 1200
```

This is only possible because `$p` is actually exposed in the public API. To get around this, you have a couple of options

One of them is to do as @RonaldSwets proposes:

```
function fact($n) {
    // 1 is the base case, like you had for $p in your code
    if ($n == 0)
      return 1;
    // otherwise return $n times the next value
    else
      return $n * fact($n - 1);
}
```

Another is to use an auxiliary function which is meant only for private use

```
// function used by `fact`
function fact_aux ($n, $p) { 
  if ($n == 0)
    return $p;
  else
    return fact_aux($n - 1, $p * $n);
}

// function meant to be used by others
function fact ($n) {
  return fact_aux($n, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. With the help of you, I finally understand recursion

Answer (score 3):

Because if the `if` condition is `true` then no `return` statement is ever encountered.  Perhaps you meant this:

```
if ($n > 1) {
    $p *= $n--;
    return fact($n, $p); // return the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You help me to understand recursions better

Answer (score 3):

You try to assign a variable which you did not pass by reference. Either pass $p by reference (`&$p`) or use a return value. In this case a return value is way better.

Secondly, `$n--` is post decrement, meaning your code does not read that nicely.

```
function fact($n) {
    if ($n == 0) return 1;
    return $n * fact($n - 1);
}

var_dump(fact(5))
```

Comment: Don't forget `0!` is actually **1**. Just change your predicate to `$n == 0` and then you're good.

Answer (score 1):

you fact only return value when `$n == 1`. When `$n > 1`, you have to return value `fact(n-1)` in `fact(n)`.